# What does "barbaro josha" mean in this conversation?

Tags: coloquialismos

In a recent online conversation:

```
Them: Entendiste lo que tenes que hacer?
Me: Si
Them: barbaro josha
```

I searched Google but couldn't find anything, it sounds like a name or something, but there was no other context. Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave more context, most importantly where these people are from. "Bárbaro" is a common way of saying "awesome" in various places, for example.

Comment: The text is missing a comma. It should be: "Barbaro, Josha". That can be translated as "Great, Josha". Josha understood his task and was congratulated.

Comment: No entendía Josha como nombre. ¿Hay algún lugar donde sea común? o ¿es una forma de decir Josh u otro nombre? 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These words are predominantly used in Argentina.

*Bárbaro* means good. If something is "bárbaro" it means that it is "More than fine".

> 7. adj. Excelente, llamativo, magnífico. *El orador estuvo bárbaro.* (from RAE)

*Josha* requires a bit more explaining. The word was spelt *josha* but it was referring to the term *joya*. *Joya* means “great”, “excellent”. For example, [this website](https://bridge.edu/tefl/blog/5-slang-words-that-will-make-you-sound-like-an-argentine/) describes *joya* as “awesome”, “right on”, and lists the expression as an essential in the Argentinian jargon. The word *joya* is also used to describe someone’s mood, eg: *Estoy joya* (“I am joya”), which means “I am happy” (compare with “I’m A-okay” or “I’m peachy”).

As for why the author wrote *josha* instead of *joya*, the term *joya* is predominantly used in Argentina. Argentinians tend to pronounce the Spanish "y” as a "sh" or “zh” (sheísmo), so the person used the literal pronunciation, which is usually done as a joke. Other examples of this phenomenon are:

> Tweet: “Estoy shorando de la emoción ” ([Source](https://twitter.com/jequi13/status/1395076670701424645?s=21)]
>
> YouTube title: “Tah shoviendo con sol xD” ([Source](https://youtu.be/oekRTZqPjO0)]

As you can see, this form of phonetic transcription is only done in very colloquial contexts. For more on Argentinian phonology, see [Rioplatense Spanish](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rioplatense_Spanish).

Comment: "Barbaro joya" is an expression in Argentine? Something like "Awesome cool"? Are you sure that there is not a comma missing. "Barbaro, joya" meaning "Great, sweetheart" or something like this.

Comment: Do we know that the person typing the original was Argentinian?

Comment: "Barbaro" is not just an Argentine expression,it could only be said that it originates from there (?), in fact it is also used a lot in Mexico or other parts since it is a "popular" word so to speak, and no, jewel is at no time to refer to something like "darling" or "sweetheart"
Attached a fragment of a movie where someone uses the term "barbarian". In this case he says: "Vieron eso, eso es ser Barbaro" (They saw that, that is to be Barbaro).- Referring to that she is cool https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXSehDcFquc @RubioRic

Comment: I am Colombian, I speak native Spanish @mdewey

Comment: I can't hardly understand your comment above. And I still don't get the full expression. Bárbaro can mean just "great", as stated in the DLE, and almost all Spanish speakers understand that. I don't know what exactly means "barbaro joya" and in which country is used as a expression.

Comment: I am sorry that you cannot understand my comments, I am not very good with English, but I felt the need to explain that "barabaro josha" does not have much science or meaning behind it, I can assume that the one who answered this simply did it in a way "lazy", some when writing do not put punctuation marks, have bad spelling or simply use the wrong spelling on purpose, such as writing like this: Instead of Que hubo (What was there) = "kiubo". Or instead of Bien (Good) = "Bn"
barbaro josha = great good or great cool @RubioRic